# return ture if first string contain all letters of second string

Tags: javascript, string

I have to check if one string contain all letters of other string .
 example : string 1 = "mary"; string 2 = "aarmy"; 
  should return true; 
 I tried to indexOf method but this will check only entire string in same
 order. please suggest me any solution.

Comment: You should show any effort and the current code that you have. You are unlikely to get a good response by dumping a question verbatim; explain what you're struggling with and provide clear debugging information.

Comment: i have to check if one string has all character of other or not .

Comment: my point was that you should show what you've tried so far, so it doesn't look as if you've just dumped a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` in a loop in the following way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < string1.length; i++)
{
    if(string2.indexOf(string1[i]) != -1)
       //This letter occurs in string2
}
```

Comment: thanks . it works :)